# Dynamics crm 2011 addlink with relationship campaignlist_association

Tags: linq, relationship, crm, microsoft-dynamics

```
Relationship relation = new Relationship("campaignlist_association");
Entity campaign = (from c in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("campaign")
               select c).FirstOrDefault<Entity>();
foreach (Guid id in listsMarketingGuid)
{
    Entity list = (from l in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("list")
               where l["listid"].Equals(id)
               select l).FirstOrDefault<Entity>();
    orgServiceContext.AddLink(campaign, relation, list);
    orgServiceContext.AddLink(list, relation, campaign);
}
orgServiceContext.SaveChanges();
```

I would like to add a relation between a marketing list and a campaign but when the SaveChanges statment is executed I got an error "Associate is not supported for CampaignItem".
Do you any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs to call method     AddItemCampaignRequest

Comment: Where did you find "AddItemCampaignRequest"?

Answer (score 1):

use Associate method as for building relationship:

```
_service.Associate(EntityLogicalName,EntityId,relationship,relatedEntities);
```

where EntityLogicalName is name of entity 
EntityId is id of entity 
relationship:wat kind of relationship
relatedentities:to which entiites u want to build relation of above entity.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error

> "Associate is not supported for CampaignItem"

when trying to associate product to campaign. This worked for me:

```
var request = new AddItemCampaignRequest
{
    CampaignId = yourCampaign.Id,
    EntityId = productToAssociate.Id,
    EntityName = ProductEntity.EntityLogicalName,
};
_serviceProxy.Execute(request);
```

Creds to [Mitch Milam](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmitchmilam/archive/2013/06/23/associating-marketing-lists-and-campaigns)

Hope this will help someone.